# filter object of objects dynamic key value

Tags: javascript, lodash

how can i filter object of objects with dynamic key value in javaScript or lodash.

my data is :

```
var names = [
  {
    name: 'c1',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value1-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c2',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value2-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c3',
    tags: {
      key3: 'value3-1',
      key4: 'value3-2',
    },
  }
]
```

and filter data is:

```
var filterData = {
  key3: { 0: 'value3-1' },
  key4: { 0: 'value3-2' }
}
```

and i expect filter and after filter show like this:

```
afterFilter = [
      {
        name: 'c3',
        tags: {
          key3: 'value3-1',
          key4: 'value3-2',
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

first console.log segment:
- filter contains keys/vals in tags
second console.log segment:
- exact same set of key/vals (also checks they are same length)

```js
var names = [{
    name: 'c1',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value1-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c2',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value2-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c3',
    tags: {
      key3: 'value3-1',
      key4: 'value3-2',
    },
  }
]
var filterData = {
  key3: 'value3-1',
  key4: 'value3-2'
}

names.push({
  name: 'c4',
  tags: {
    key1: 'pew',
    key2: 'pew pew',
    key4: 'value3-2',
    key3: 'value3-1'
  }
})

// filter for if _contains_ key/values of filterData
console.log(
  names.filter(({
    tags
  }) => Object.entries(filterData).every(([k, v]) => tags[k] === v))
)

// filter for only exact same key/values of filterData order-insensitive
const count = Object.keys(filterData).length
console.log(
  names.filter(
    ({
      tags
    }) =>
    (tags =>
      tags.length === count && tags.every(([k, v]) => filterData[k] === v))
    (Object.entries(tags))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the format of your filter data, so I am assuming this will also work:

```
var filterdata = {
   key3: 'value3-1',
   key4: 'value3-2',
};
```

With this, you can then do a `.filter()` on your names data set:

```
const keys = Object.keys(filterData);
const res = names.filter((name) => {
   let flag = true;

   keys.forEach((key) => {
      if (filterData[key] !== name.tags[key]) flag = false;
   });

   return flag;
});

// res === afterFilter
```

If you keep the key names the same you will be able to leave some things out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: maybe i receive this filter Data:
var filterData = {
    key3: 'value3-1',
   key2: 'value1-2'
};

Answer (score 0):

You can do something on these lines.

```
var names = [
  {
    name: 'c1',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value1-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c2',
    tags: {
      key1: 'value2-1',
      key2: 'value1-2',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'c3',
    tags: {
      key3: 'value3-1',
      key4: 'value3-2',
    },
  }
]

var path = "tags.key1";
var value = "value1-1"
var filtered = []
names.forEach(elem => {
  var arr = path.split('.')
  // make a copy so that you do not operate on original entry
  var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elem));
  while(arr.length) {

    item = item && item[arr[0]]
    arr.shift();
  }
  if (item === value) {
    filtered.push(elem)
  }
})

// Filtered is result
console.log(filtered)
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kishin-karra/pen/dyYxEoZ